# Where Have I gone wrong with this Javascript JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON file using javascript and display just the images in the array. What am I doing wrong here and how would I go about fixing it?? **There is no output on the screen when the code is executed. I thought this would output images, but nothing is happening period.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script 'type=text/javascript' 'src=js.js'></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="ajax link was here"></script>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>images</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class = "movie">

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript File

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.get('http://54.243.128.130/search/movies_list/?q=inception', function (data, image) {

        var movie = JSON.parse(data);

        for (var x = 0; x < movie.length; x++) {
            var mov = movie[x];
            //var elm = '<div class = "movie"><img src = "'+mov.img+'"></div>';
            var elm = mov.img;
            $('.movie').prepend(elm);

        }

    }, 'text');

});
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't know, where *have* you gone wrong? What error are you getting? What is your expected outcome? What is the *actual* outcome? How are they different? Give us *something* to work with here.

Comment: In all likelihood, if your server's returning a JSON header, the data variable will already have been converted to an array

Comment: @Pete It's not (content-type is `text/html`)

Comment: Could this be a cross-domain issue primarily? (Ignoring the syntax errors you have and the fact that you're iterating the wrong set of data).

Comment: Possibly. If you're looking to loop through the results, @MrGuy should be looking at `movie.results`, though...

Comment: @MartyWallace That's probably the issue. MrGuy, what URL are you using to access the HTML page above?

Comment: @MrGuy - holy grail of web debugging is Use Chrome Developer tool / Firefox Firebug or Safar Web Inspector.. you can even put breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

No need to parse yourself jsut use `$.getJSON` instead.

```
$.getJSON('http://54.243.128.130/search/movies_list/?q=inception', function (data, image) {

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        var mov = data[x];
        //var elm = '<div class = "movie"><img src = "'+mov.img+'"></div>';
        var elm = mov.img;
        $('.movie').prepend(elm);

    }

}
```

Additionally you ahve the structure wrong. That page is returning something like:

```
{
   "query": "the value of your q parameter"
   "results": []
}
```

So you also need to modify your loop and access of the data. So putting it together:

```
$.getJSON('http://54.243.128.130/search/movies_list/?q=inception', function (data, image) {

        var movies = data.results;

        for (var x = 0; x < movies.length; x++) {
            var mov = movies[x];
            //var elm = '<div class = "movie"><img src = "'+mov.img+'"></div>';
            var elm = mov.img;
            $('.movie').prepend(elm);

        }

    }
```

And lastly if this isnt on the same server as your code you will need to use `jsonp` or create a local proxy to make the external request.

Comment: It is not outputting anything at all. Nothing shows up on the page when loaded

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you might want to change

```
<script 'type=text/javascript' 'src=js.js'></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

And can you describe what error/problem you are having?

Answer (score -2):

JSON.parse function returns dictionary not array. So let's say we got a dictionary as an output of JSON.parse:
var movie={a:1,b:2,c:3};
Then you should iterate on it like that:

```
for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(movie).length;i++){
    var mov = movie[Object.keys(movie)[i]];
    var elm = mov.img;
    $('.movie').prepend(elm
}
```

Comment: They're called _objects_ in JS, not dictionaries.

Comment: Also, if the string is something like `"[1,2,3]"` then `JSON.parse` will indeed return an array

Comment: Oops sorry. 2 big mistakes, thanks guys :)